# How to do memory management in Arc in ios?

Tags: ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I am working on an application which is uses ARC, but some how memory is not releasing on changing views. Instead, it is growing every time.
You can see in picture. I am using simple animation and corner radius to buttons and view. What am i doing wrong?  Any help to reduce memory heap will be appreciated.
Thanks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUPAD.png

Edit:

```
Using Animation.

[UIView animateWithDuration:.25 animations:^{
    view.alpha = 1.0;
    view.hidden = NO;
    view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,1);
}];

Using quartcore.

button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
button.layer.borderColor = kBorderLightGrayColor.CGColor;
```

Comment: Nobody is going to be able to tell you what you're doing wrong without seeing your code

Comment: but it is a big application. How can i provide you all ?

Comment: You need to narrow down your issue to a problem that is specific enough to be on-topic for this site

Comment: Thanks dan, i am new here on this site.

Comment: Have you tried the leaks tool in Instruments? that should help you identify where memory is leaking

Comment: @Paulw11 i have attached image. It was growing memory on coreanimation and showing quartzcore framework. I am using it for setting cornerradius and borders and stuff like that.